# how to format currency based on locale within LUA

Tags: lua, locale, coronasdk, currency

How could I format a number into a currency format based on the locale?  I'm working in LUA.

Background: Using Corona SDK which uses LUA.  Can detect locale (e.g. US, JA etc) from mobile device using Corona, however then if I wanted to format a number for currency in that region/locale is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
assert(os.setlocale('fr_FR'))
print(12.34)
```

Without seeing your code where you use the currency it's difficult to help.